# When is a good time to ask for a next academic position?

Tags: phd, advisor, postdocs

As a final year PhD student with less than 1 year to go before the PhD is completed, I am interested in continuing in the same group as a PostDoc. However, I do not know if I should wait until I am asked or should I ask if my supervisor has funding for me to continue as a PostDoc.

About how many months before (or after) the PhD ends is it the most suitable for supervisors to comment concretely if they can offer me the next position?

Comment: A word of caution: doing your postdoc as the same place as your PhD is usually seen as a poor career move. You might have trouble building a comparable research profile to your peers, with whom you will compete for a small number of long-term jobs later.

Comment: I understand the concerns. However, I have other priorities: as a non-EU citizen I would like to become a EU-citizen which would be possible within this PostDoc tenure. Plus the place I work at is becoming the hub for my field of research in Europe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The time to act is now. You need lead time to arrange any future position. You should have a conversation with your supervisor about your future. It can be wide ranging. Ask for advice about where and how to achieve it. Include a request (or a query) about staying on and asking if that is possible (desirable, mutually advantageous...).

But you also need their help even if you won't be staying. It is best to develop a plan for that however it needs to play out.

Now is the time.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I acted on it, and got the position I wanted!